# Do you think about this code in kernel link_path_walk()

Tags: kernel

I wanted to print the path of file, so I wrote this code in `link_path_walk(...)` function in `namei.c`

It resulted in a kernel panic.

Is this code valid?

```
char* path_str = NULL;*/
char* ret;*/
int flag_fsm = 0;*/
ret = strstr(name,"_FSM");*/


// add this code - start*/


if(ret != NULL){*/
    path_str = (char*)kmalloc(sizeof(name),GFP_KERNEL);*/
    strcpy(path_str,name);  */
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s, link_path_walk() in vfs\n",path_str);*/
    flag_fsm = 1;*/
}*/


// add this code - finish*/


while (*name=='/')*/
    name++;*/
if (!*name){*/


// add this code - start*/


if(ret != NULL){*/
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s, return from link_path_walk() in vfs\n",path_str);*/
    kfree(path_str);*/
}*/

// add this code - finish*/
    return 0;*/
} */
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have `name++` in there somewhere, it's a certainty that `name` is a pointer rather than an array.

Hence this code segment:

```
path_str = (char*)kmalloc(sizeof(name),GFP_KERNEL);
strcpy(path_str,name);
```

is rather dangerous since `sizeof(name)` is the size of a pointer rather than the length of a string.

For example:

```
char *name = "way more bytes than in a pointer,"
             " and more than the minimum kmalloc size";
```

will cause you no end of grief since you'll allocate four or eight bytes for `path_str` then try and copy that long string into it.

The allocation should probably be more along the lines of:

```
path_str = kmalloc (strlen (name) + 1, GFP_KERNEL);
```

You should also check the return value from `kmalloc`, it can return NULL if it can't find suitable memory. This holds for userland code but is even *more* important in a kernel since violating memory protection there is much worse than in userland.